Can't install bootloader on my SSD
I had a dual boot setup with Ubuntu and Windows 10. After upgrading to Windows 11, something happened to my GRUB/Linux partitions, so I decided to reinstall Ubuntu. You can see the full context in my other question (I still have GRUB 2.06 installed).
I'm trying to install Ubuntu 24.04 and am facing several issues. First of all, the installer doesn't recognize my Windows installation and doesn't offer the option to install Ubuntu alongside it. I chose manual partitioning and tried to format and reuse the partitions from my original setup: /, /home and Swap.
The problem is that the installer doesn't allow me to install the bootloader on my SSD (Crucial, 525 GB) — the option is disabled. I can only install it on the bootable media I'm using to load the installation (SanDisk 33.3 GB).


I think, this is because of VFAT and NTFS formats on sda.

Did Windows turn bitlocker on? Or is fast startup on in Windows which sets hibernation flag and prevents the Linux NTFS driver from seeing the NTFS partitions?Or an UEFI update turn on locked boot entries? Check UEFI & Windows settings.

Ive checked bitlocker and fast boot. both are disabled.
Ive tried to anlyze the disc with testdisk and it recognize my /dev/sd6, /dev/sda/7 as linux partitions. At this stage I would just like to install a fresh ubuntu distro.

I created the bootable media using a GPT partition scheme instead of MBR, and the issue seems to be resolved (though I haven't installed it yet). As I mentioned in another question, Windows 11 likely converted my partitions from MBR to GPT, which caused the problem. Before proceeding with a fresh installation, I want to remove the boot option associated with my current, non-functional Ubuntu installation using efibootmgr. Is it safe to do this if I'm planning to reinstall Ubuntu?
